# Найти в Dataframe повторяющиеся значения через каждые три строчки

Tags: python, pandas, комбинаторика

Есть задача по комбинаторике:

> В ящике 5 апельсинов и 4 яблока. Наудачу выбираются 3 фрукта. Какова
> вероятность, что все три фрукта – апельсины?
>
> Необходимо проверить экспериментально в Python. (вероятность - 0.119)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

U = ["orange"]*5 + ['apple']*4
# наполняем урну
n = 120000
# количество экспериментов
A = pd.DataFrame({"A":list(map(lambda a: random.choice([random.choice(U)]), range(n)))})
# формируем выборку
```

Есть ли способ посчитать значения Dataframe через каждые три элемента, которые будут содержать только 'orange' ? Планировал полученное число разделить на 40000, чтобы получить вероятность.

Comment: выбрать через каждые три элемента - не проблема: `A.iloc[::3,0] == "orange"`, посчитать тоже: `(A.iloc[::3,0] == "orange").sum()`. но вот с чего вы взяли, что выбирать нужно именно так? три наугад это не через три элемента.

Comment: Зачем датафрейм? [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/233990)

Comment: неплохая активность в вопросе)

Comment: @D.Vinogradov Потому что мы любим `Pandas` ))

Answer (score 2):

А, я понял. У вас подход к эксперименту неправильный, результат поэтому получается не тот, который ожидается. Фактически, вы не соблюдаете условие, что у вас есть ящик из которого вы вынимаете фрукты. У вас есть склад с ящиками и вы вынимаете 3 фрукта из любых ящиков, а не только из одного, из-за этого получается не верный результат. Если брать фрукты из одного ящика, то с каждым взятым апельсином вероятность следующего апельсина сильно уменьшается. А если брать со склада, то вероятность падает не настолько сильно.

Как посчитать верный результат:

- брать для эксперимента строго один ящик, а не множество ящиков
- перемешивать каждый раз фрукты в ящике
- брать три первых фрукта
- проверять, что все они апельсины
- разделить число получившихся случаев "3 апельсина" на число экспериментов

```
import random

# наполняем урну
data = ["orange"]*5 + ['apple']*4

# количество экспериментов
n = 120_000

# выборка
k = 3

positive = 0
for _ in range(n):
    random.shuffle(data)
    result = all(x == 'orange' for x in data[:k])
    positive += result
print(positive/n)
```

Пример вывода:

```
0.118875
```

Вот это уже похоже на искомый результат.

Проверим цифры аналитически. Если мы берём апельсины из ящика, где их изначально 5 из 9, то вероятность взять 3 апельсина подряд будет:

```
print(5/9 * 4/8 * 3/7)
# 0.11904761904761905
```

А если мы берём апельсины из большого склада, то вероятность с каждым взятым апельсином будет падать очень незначительно, можно сказать вообще не будет падать:

```
print((5/9)**3)
# 0.1714677640603567
```

Именно эти цифры мы и наблюдаем в правильном и в неправильном экспериментах.

Answer (score 1):

Я не совсем уверен, что вы в принципе правильно пытаетесь проверить вероятность опытным путём, но что касается выборки, я бы советовал использовать не каждый третий ряд

```
(A.iloc[::3,0] == "orange").sum()
```

, а воспользоваться методом `sample`:

```
random.seed(42)
# количество экспериментов
A = pd.DataFrame({"A":list(map(lambda a: random.choice([random.choice(U)]), range(n)))})
res = A.sample(frac=0.33, replace=False, random_state=42).value_counts()["orange"]
```

> 22179

Answer (score 1):

по сути это реализация метода Монте-Карло, немного подправил ваш код:

```
from random import sample

U = [0]*5 + [1]*4
n = 120000

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":list(map(lambda a: sum(sample(U,3))==0, range(n)))})
print(df.head())
'''
       A
0  False
1  False
2   True
3   True
4  False
'''

# вероятность
df['A'].mean()
0.11896666666666667
```

Comment: Вот это хорошо, хотя опять же непонятно, зачем тут в общем-то `Pandas`, среднее и без него можно посчитать )

Comment: `print(sum(sum(sample(U,3))==0 for _ in range(n))/n)`

Comment: @CrazyElf, да так и есть, может просто это они возможности pandas так изучают

Comment: Да, ситуация непонятная. Может автор вопроса вернётся и что-то прояснит в итоге )

Comment: @CrazyElf , все верно, мы изучаем Pandas, по этому и решение нужно было сделать через него)

Answer (score 0):

ПОДХОД К ЭКСПЕРИМЕНТУ У ВАС НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ.

Можете посмотреть тут код, чтобы чему-то научиться. Но для правильного результата смотрите другой мой ответ.

Поменял несколько ваш код.

- чтобы упростить дальнейшие вычисления я сразу проверяю, что выпал именно `orange` и ставлю 1 если да
- я делаю в датафрейме группы по 3 элемента с помощью `groupby`
- дальше я суммирую те единички по группам
- если в группе получилось три единички, то это то, что мы ищем
- результат варьируется, но не похож на тот, который вы предполагали

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# наполняем урну
data = ["orange"]*5 + ['apple']*4

# количество экспериментов
n = 120_000

# формируем выборку
df = pd.DataFrame({"data": [random.choice(data) == 'orange' for _ in range(n)], "group": [i // 3 for i in range(n)]})

# вычисляем
print((df.groupby("group").sum() == 3).sum()['data'] / 40_000)
```

Пример вывода:

```
0.1725
```

Тот же эксперимент без пандас. С таким же результатом:

```
import random

# наполняем урну
data = ["orange"]*5 + ['apple']*4

# количество экспериментов
n = 120_000

# выборка
k = 3

print(sum(sum(random.choice(data) == 'orange' for _ in range(k)) == 3 for _ in range(n)) / n)
```

Пример вывода:

```
0.17134166666666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Не надо никаких датафреймов, у Питона самого есть модуль `random`:

```
import random

INBOX = 5 * ["O"] + 4 * ["A"]
WANTED = 3 * ["O"]
N = 100_000

wanted = 0

for __ in range(N):
    if random.sample(INBOX, k=3) == WANTED:
        wanted += 1 
       
print(f"Вероятность, что все три фрукта – апельсины: {wanted/N}")
```

---

*Вывод (например):*

> ```
>  Вероятность, что все три фрукта – апельсины: 0.11821
> ```

Comment: `set(selection) <= set(APPLES)` - что-то я не уверен, что вы тут что-то правильное вычисляете

Comment: @CrazyElf, `<=` значит «является подмножеством» .

Comment: А, ну да. А теперь посмотрите внимательно на условие. `APPLES` - это не апельсины. Если поменяете на апельсины, получится другая цифра ;)

Comment: И ещё обратите внимание на описание метода `random.choices`: "Return a k sized list of population elements chosen **with replacement**". В вопросе ничего не сказано про то, что апельсин кладётся обратно в корзину перед вытаскиванием следующего. У вас получится та цифра, которая получилась в моём ответе по неправильной методике эксперимента.

Comment: @CrazyElf, вы дважды прав («`APPLES` – это не апельсины» и «`random.choices`: "Return a k sized list of population elements chosen **with replacement**"») - большое вам спасибо!